# Register-ObjectEvent ghost instance running

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, filesystemwatcher

I am using `New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` / `Register-ObjectEvent` (Powershell) to monitor a folder for new files and perform action. It is being run as a scheduled task under a service user account, and as part of the "action", it executes a Python script.

I changed the Python script recently, and I can observe the new behaviour when triggering the 'event', however, in my logs (logged by the Python script) I still see log lines that I have already removed. It is as if there is a "ghost" or "cached" instance of my filesystem watcher running.

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher 
$watcher.Path = "\\ab\b\c"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action = 
        { 
        # call python script to do all the work
        $pythonPath = 'C:\a\b\c.py args'
        Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python3\python.exe" -ArgumentList @($pythonPath) -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait -RedirectStandardError psstderr.txt -RedirectStandardOutput psstout.txt
        }

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action

while ($true) { Start-Sleep 5 }
```

I tried `Get-EventSubscriber` and `Get-FileSystemWatcher` but they are not giving me anything as I'm not in the same session. I tried restarting the server, but that didn't help either.

Now I am thinking that this could be because I am not closing down the process with a Stop-Process - but when I see the running processes with Get-Process, I don't see Python running.

TLDR; upon events, filesystem watcher executes a "cached" version of the python script which no longer exists on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing the "Start in" location in the task scheduler, when editing my task. When I specify the "Start in" to be my scripts folder (where my file watcher ps resides), I no longer see the "ghost/cached" logs.